# Автовыведение типа

Tags: c++, типы-данных

я только начинаю свой путь в С++ поэтому задался таким вопросом как : Стоит ли вообще использовать `auto` в указании переменой или же лучше указывать конкретный тип данных (`int,float`и так далее ).Прошу помочь разобраться в этом вопросе .Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ох, нет тут четких правил... Я лично за то, чтоб автовывод применять только для шаблонов и длинных (*и очевидных*) вещей типа `std::map<string,vector<string>>::const_iterator` :), а уж `int`, `float` и так далее - только явно.

Comment: Тут есть четкое правило - если тип переменной определяется инициализатором (т.е. имеется зависимость), то следует использовать `auto`, а если нет - то явный тип. Главное различать ситуацию, когда типы совпадают, но зависимости нет. Такой подход позволяет удешевить дальнейшую поддержку и модификацию кода.

Comment: `auto` может и к проблемам привести. При банальной опечатке. Допустим есть `int* ptr = new int; auto value = *ptr;`, но по ошибке напишем `auto value = &ptr;` и компилятор не ругнётся.

Comment: @user7860670 А потом получить массу геморроя на неявных приведениях типов, например... Да и код хуже читаемый - когда надо лезть смотреть, что там за тип, исходя из инициализатора...

Comment: @Harry Что значит "получить массу геморроя на неявных приведениях типов"? За счет чего в  коде с выведением типов окажется больше неявных приведений по сравнению с соответствующим кодом, использующим явное указание типов? Типы переменных же остаются одинаковы. Скорее даже наоборот, при переходе к выведению типов хотя бы некоторые неявные приведения необходимо будет сделать явными. А с читабельностью что не так? Я вот тип переменной обычно смотрю в подсказе в IDE независимо от того, задавался ли он выше, при введении переменной, или выводился там автоматически.

Comment: @user7860670 Это к вашему "*Такой подход позволяет удешевить дальнейшую поддержку и модификацию кода*" - модифицируете 1 на 1.0, а потом будете искать, где же ошибка... Или наоборот - 1.0 на 1, и деление сразу станет целочисленным :) "*Говорил ему Балда с укоризною: не гонялся бы ты, поп, за дешевизною...*" (с) А.С. Пушкин

Comment: @Harry Если замена деления с плавающей точкой на целочисленного деление является некорректным, то и тип переменной не должен становиться целочисленным в зависимости от инициализатора, а использование вывода типа при отсутствии зависимости от типа инициализатора изначально было некорректным.